# Fast way to find substrings of a query

Tags: algorithm, performance, substring

I have a practical problem to do with finding any strings that form the beginning of a given query string and I can't find a suitable method for doing it quickly at scale.  (specifically not trying to find strings that themselves begin with the query, it's the other way round).

So for example I would have a dataset like this:

```
Does she drink coffee
They speak English
They speak Turkish 
They speak
What colour is the jumper
```

And if a query was given such as `They speak English at work` then I would want to match `They speak English` and `They speak` from the dataset, and a query of `They speak Turkish at home` would want to match `They speak Turkish` and `They speak`.

Everything I have used for string indexing previously works the other way round.  E.g. a dataset of complete strings and the query being the sub-string.

**In terms of the dataset:**

- Size is in the tens of millions (and growing, it will never reduce)
- Every string in the set is unique
- The strings are of variable length between 13 and 2,000 characters
- 13 is a hard limit, no query can be fewer characters than this

I've considered a simple brute force check but it's too slow for my use case.  I ideally need something that is doable in <10ms on fairly standard hardware.

I've looked suffix trees but unless I'm misunderstanding (which I very much might be I'm more a web dev than a computer scientist) they wouldn't be suitable for this use case.

The closest thing I've thought of is to trim all of my dataset to the smallest length and put them in a hashmap, then use this as a way to limit the amount of searches done to only entries that are guaranteed to have the same initial 13 characters.  The problem with that is it won't be at all balanced as there is some level of duplication at the beginning of strings.  Some of my map entries (tested on prod data) would have >100k entries and would lead to inconsistent performance particularly as the set grows.

Comment: Which are you more interested in: consistent performance or fast performance?  If the former, you could always add a delay to let the quicker searches match the slower ones.

Comment: Inconsistent is fine I suppose as long as it is fast.  My concern is that I won't be able to reliably keep track or predict what goes in the set so I could quickly end up with some very large buckets without realising.  So far the hashmap thing works pretty effectively, it just feels wrong and I feel like I must be missing something.

Comment: I'd probably not build this by hand.

Comment: I agree @DaveNewton... I'd rather just use a known solution I just can't find anything that does it this way round. All of my searching has found things to do with searching for a given substring in a set of complete strings rather than this way round

Comment: What prevents you from realizing that a bucket got large?

Comment: Is this a trie, but with a form of "stop markers" on some nodes to indicate they should be returned in the result set? E.g., when you traverse to `t-h-e-y- -s-p-e-a-k` there'd be an indication the result should be returned, even if it can continue on to `t-h-e-y- -s-p-e-a-k- -t-u-r-k-i-s-h` (also returned)? Are the "terminals" known, or unbounded? It may also be that an ML model would end up being a better fit if things are truly arbitrary beyond a certain point. Are the "initiators" known or also unbounded?

Comment: @DaveNewton yes that sounds promising for stop markers.  Traversing and then checking for markers as I go seems sensible.  I've not considered this thank you... I will look for trie implementations that will account for this use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view millions should fit in RAM so we can create a data structure that stays in RAM.

I would create a prefix-tree (based on words, not characters) and than traverse the tree with the query as long as possible. All prefixes along the way are matches.

```
   What colour is the jumper
  / 
 +  Does - she - drink - coffee*
  \
   \               English*
    They - speak*< 
                   Turkish*
```

P.s. * marks end of an valid entry

Finding all matches would be `O(n)`  (n is length of request)